# Creating a raw html component in Ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

I'm attempting to make a design guide where I show code as html or css.

My understanding is that I should be making a component because I can use the {{yield}} to get the code do display like below.

Usage:

```html
{{#raw-output}}
  <div>test</div>
{{/raw-output}}
```

components/raw-output.hbs:

```html
<pre>
<code>
    {{{yield}}}
</code>
</pre>
```

My only issue is that I cannot figure out how to output the raw code in HtmlBars.

EDIT: Final product

```
//raw-output.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {
        var $element = $(this.get('element')), 
        $code = $("code", $element), 
        html = $code.html();
        $code.empty().text(html);
    }
 });

//raw-output.hbs

<code>
    {{{yield}}}
</code>


//usage
{{#raw-output}}
    <div>name</div> 
{{/raw-output}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it in the same way as you mentioned. In the `didInsertElement` of your component, get the code lines, `escape` them and then show the escaped lines.

Working Example : [Twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/81cc08a8134d19713a4c?numColumns=1)

Answer (score 1):

Usage:

```
{{raw-output model='<div style="background: red">test</div>'}}
```

components/raw-output.hbs:

```
<pre>
<code>
    {{model}}
</code>
</pre>
```

You don't need to use `yield`. Use normal property like `model`.

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/eef550f085b5f92b9957)
- [Full code behind demo.](https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/eef550f085b5f92b9957)

Answer (score 0):

As an option try [ember-code-snippet](https://github.com/ef4/ember-code-snippet) addon.

This is an Ember component (and ember-cli addon) that lets you render code snippets within your app. The code snippets can live in their own dedicated files or you can extract blocks of code from your application itself. Features:

- syntax highlighting.
- ember-cli's auto-reload will pick up changes to any of the snippet files.
- the component uses file extensions to help highlight.js guess the right language.

For example, this addon is used in [addepar/ember-table demo](http://addepar.github.io/ember-table/#/simple).